# Java. REST service + Jasper reports. Cannot print label (or cannot find)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jasper-reports, saxparser

I have a java program which is use for label printing (Argox, Godex printers 10x20cm). I need to add more information in theese labels. The problem is that i dont have source code so i used Java Decompiler for get .class files.

I had added those .class files to new java project + files that was near .jar file.
Rest server started succesfully, my java project receive information from tomcat webapp, but there are some error, and i cannot print my file.

There is console:
http://pastebin.com/c09PrWcZ

There are java code where error appears: 
http://pastebin.com/1WuKthWp  (it is one of 5 files, but other is for REST start, Property options, etc.

I am realy new on java, jersey and rest service.

Comment: @PetterFriberg u mean library .jar file of jasper compiler version? 
And what is heading of my reports?
I am using : 5.0.0 version of jasperreports, applet fonts and javaflow.

Comment: @PetterFriberg No i'am using old jrxml file with 7 values in that .jrxml. But now i am trying to fill that .jrxml file with same old 7 values + 2 new :)

I am not using jasper-compiler.jar

Comment: So you have different jrxml, and I'm sorry to say that you are using a jasper compiler "JasperCompileManager.compileReport" in your code. Jasper have changed from DDT to XML schema with different version, thats why I like to see the header of your jrxml, if this is not your problem, your in for some "xerces from hell" problem..... I can try to guess an answer to your problem, but if you give more info I can be more precis

Comment: @PetterFriberg i want to give u more information, but i dont understand what are you asking. Maybe this is header?? http://picpaste.com/pic-6A5H7x36.png

Comment: I will try to answer, give you some clues... to work on .

Comment: @PetterFriberg `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->`

Comment: As I understand the application was running you have modified the jrxml files (added some info) so now it's using xml-schema (3 line), maybe the previous jrxml was with another version?... check what they had before (see solution 2)

Comment: I used to make solution 2 but it still gives me the same error of creating sax parser. Maybe i need to add newiest library of xerces?

Comment: What was the heading (3 lines) before you edited the jrxml?. What heading do you have now!.... check this before you turn to xerces hell..

Comment: @PetterFriberg   before editing : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="prod_label_1" language="groovy" pageWidth="566" pageHeight="297" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="554" leftMargin="8" rightMargin="4" topMargin="9" bottomMargin="8" uuid="09331097-95fb-4430-b00e-b3ad9a57e57f">`

Comment: @PetterFriberg after editing : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="prod_label_1" language="groovy" pageWidth="566" pageHeight="297" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="554" leftMargin="8" rightMargin="4" topMargin="9" bottomMargin="8" uuid="09331097-95fb-4430-b00e-b3ad9a57e57f">`

Comment: They are both schema based... if you are sure (note, you should not open with jasper soft to check.... but with a textpad!!), you need to check for xerces problem, whats bothering me is that if it was working previously it was more likely that before opening with jaser soft is had ddt definition... old jtd-compiler... in your project you have a jdt-compiler or a ecj jar

Comment: @PetterFriberg i deleted all my .jar files and copied all from lib folder near compiled .jar file. now i have no errors :))

Comment: then we had a "xerces from hell" problem, search for it on the web you are not the first one (google 29.100 results ; )......... Thanks for the accepted answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your stacktrace is

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
```

Lets guess why.

1. **"Xerces from hell"** problem.

It is not using the correct version of xerces library to compile your .jrxml, you may have wrong xerces library in classpath, you may have many...

**Solution:**

Check the jasper report distribution for your version of jasper report, included correct xerces jar's and remove other xerces implementations.

**EDIT**: users solution in comment:

*"i deleted all my .jar files and copied all from lib folder near compiled .jar file. now i have no errors :))"*

2. **Different version** of jdt-compiler and .jrxml format

In the beginning jasper report was using DTD (if you check the xml of the .jrxml file) you would find:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
```

Then they switch to XML-schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Entrata" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" isFloatColumnFooter="true">
```

So if you open an old report (DTD) and edit with es. iReport/Jaspersoft Studio  it will change the header from DTD to XML-schema and your old version of jdt-compiler will not recognize this format.

**Solution**

Manually switch back to DOCTYPE definition in jrxml file, and remove schema  definition from jasper report tag (attention set iReport/Jaspersoft studio to work with old version (settings, compatibility), so it does not add tags/attribute that are not supported)

or 
update jasper report to new version (suggested) and check that all you files have schema definition